# While loop will not change index

Tags: python, list, indexing, while-loop

I need to write a code in Python that returns the first positive number in a list using a while loop. This is what I have, but it's not working.

```
def positive(num):
    n= num[0]

### Can't change anything above
```

first I tried:

```
    i = 0
    while n <= 0:
        i += 1
```

but that didn't work so I tried:

```
    i = 0
    while i < len(num):
        n = num[i]
        while n <= 0:
            i += 1

##### Can't change below

    return n
```

I feel like I understand how to use a while loop, but changing the index of the list is what is tripping me up.

Comment: "I need to write a code .. using a while loop" Why is that? A ``for`` loop is adequate for such a problem. Are you aware of ``if`` and ``break``? In ``while n >= 0: i += 1``, how do you think ``n`` changes between iterations?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for loop` which basically is the same as a while loop:

```
def first_neg(some_list):
    for item in some_list:
        if item < 0:
            return item
```

Or as a `while` variation:

```
def first_neg(some_list):
    i = 0
    while (i < len(some_list)):
        if some_list[i] < 0:
            return some_list[i]
        i += 1
```

There also exist so called generator functions, e.g. `itertools.dropwhile()`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6]

rest = dropwhile(lambda x: x >= 0, lst)
print(next(rest))
```

All of them will yield

```
-5
```

Comment: What about the case in which there are no negative numbers in the list?

Comment: @zingergi: Of course, you should add some error management, e.g. `None`, `False`, `try/except`, etc.

Comment: Yep. Btw in your while loop, `i` cannot be `= len(some_list)` (out of bounds).

Comment: @zingergi: You're absolutely right, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by MisterMiyagi, it's preferable to use a `for` loop. You can use a `while` loop as well:

```
def first_neg(num):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(num)):
        if(num[i] < 0):
            return num[i]
        i += 1
    return 1 # no negative numbers found
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us 1st see what is wrong in your code, or what needs to be fixed

```
i = 0
while n <= 0:
    i += 1
```

Here, you used good logic, but there is one issue. Your `while` loop runs until `n<=0`, which is correct when n is your current number.
In your code, you are just updating `i`(index) and not the current number.

For example, take the `num=[-2,-3,4,5]`, your function should return `4`. Let us dry-run your while loop.
before 1st iteration:

```
n=-2, i=0
```

Loop condition : `n<=0` is satisfied, therefore loop runs and `i+=1`
after 1st iteration (which means before 2nd iteration):

```
n=-2, i=1
```

Remember, we did not perform any operation on `n` so it remains as it is.
Again Loop condition: `n<=0` is satisfied because -2<=0
So we do `i+=1`
after 2nd iteration (which means before 3rd iteration):

```
n=-2, i=2
```

Did you notice that in this way, the while loop condition will never break?
Therefore, this way, your while loop will run infinitely with no output.

So, the biggest question that comes to our mind is - **what the hell should we do then?**
The simple answer is, update `n`, just like below -

```
i = 0
while n <= 0:
    i += 1
    n=num[i]
```

Now, when we run this, `n` (which is the current element) will get updated in every iteration of the loop. That is for every iteration, the values of `n` and `i` will be as follows:

iteration 1:
before this iteration: `i=0, n=-2`
loop condition: `n<=0` (satisfied)
after this iteration: `i=1, n=-3 (n= num[i] , that is n=num[1]=-3)`

iteration 2:
before: `i=1, n=-3`
condition: `n<=0` (satisfied)
after:i=2, n=4

iteration 3:
before: `i=2, n=4`
condition: `n<=0` (not satisfied)
after: loop does not run

Therefore, after the termination of the loop, we have `i` as `2` which is the first index of a positive number.

There is still a small issue with this code.

May I ask you what will happen when all elements of num are negative?
That is when no positive element exists in num array/list

The loop condition `n<=0` where `n` is the current element will always be satisfied so `i` will be updated to `i+1` after every iteration.

Consider when `i=length-1` and we are entering the while loop again, let us check the loop condition: `n=num[i]=num[length-1]` and `n<=0`
So we enter into the loop and do:

```
i+=1
```

that is `i=(length-1)+1`
that is `i=length`
and now
`n=num[i]=num[length]` and we all know that in python indexing starts from `0` and ends at `length-1`.
So, what do you think will happen when we will try to access an element at index length?

Tada , we will get IndexError. Have a look at below code for better understanding.

```
a=[1,2,3]
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[3])
```

Output:

```
1                                                                                                                       
2                                                                                                                       
3                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                      
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>                                                                                   
    print(a[3])                                                                                                         
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So what should we do to handle this error in our while loop?
Just place another condition that the loop should run till `i<length` that is the loop now becomes

```
i = 0
while i<len(num) and n <= 0:
    i += 1
    n=num[i]
```

So, yes, now it is complete.
I have written a complete function below. Here, in this function, instead of using `n=num[i]` and then `n<=0` in loop condition, I am directly using `num[i]` in loop condition.

```
def first_positive(num):
    i=0    # i is the current index
    while(i<len(num) and num[i]<=0):  # i<len(num) means run the while loop until there are elements in the num list
        i+=1
    if i==len(num):   # when there are no positive elements present in the list
        return "No positive element found"
    else:
        return num[i]
print(first_positive([-2,-3,5,10]))     # prints 5
print(first_positive([-2,-3,-5,10]))    # prints 10
print(first_positive([-2,-3,-5,-10]))   # prints No positive element found
```

Comment: Nice! Could you explain what you changed and why it works so others who view this can learn?

Comment: @abagh0703 Please have a look. I hope it is fine now. Please do upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: much better! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep

```
def first_neg(num):
    n= num[0]
```

the above part, you can do something like this:

```
def first_neg(num):
  n = num[0]
  i = 1
  while n >= 0 and i<len(num):
    n = num[i]
    i += 1
  if n < 0 : return n
  #else return some error msg saying that no negative num is in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

You just gotta increment i to move the index

`

```
def get_first_neg(num):
    i = 0
    while i < len(num):
        if num[i] < 0:
           return num[i]
        i = i + 1 # or i += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    li=[0,1,2,3,4,5,-2,7,8,9,-1]
    i=0
    flag=0
    while(i<len(li)):
       if(li[i]<0):
          flag=1
          break
       i+=1
if(flag==1):
   print('no is found',li[i])
    
else:
  print('no not found')
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.